# jenkins building files within same project/package

Tags: java, eclipse, jenkins

Jenkins newbie here and i'm trying to learn/figure out Jenkins and I could surely use some of you help. When I say newbie, I mean it, I literally just built my first file and tried to run it, I was having trouble for the longest time and the reason for that was because I had declared a "package" in my class and the run was failing due to that.

```
package testing;
public class HelloWorld {
public static void main(String[] args) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
System.out.println("Hello World");
testing123(false,false);
}

public static void testing123(boolean weekday, boolean vacation) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
if (!weekday || vacation) {
System.out.println("You're going to sleep-in");
}   else {
System.out.println("You're not going to sleep-in");
}
}
```

Error:

```
C:\Users\xxxx\workspace\test\src\testing>javac HelloWorld.java 

C:\Users\xxxx\workspace\test\src\testing>java HelloWorld 
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: HelloWorld (wrong name: testing/HelloWorld)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
```

Directory: C:\Users\xxxx\workspace\test\src\testing

Jenkins was failing because I had put the directory (from where Jenkins pulls files) as the testing folder so understandably when I went to go run HelloWorld it would return back with a file not found....

My question is, what do I do if I have multiple files in the package (I have another class that calls this one) so I want to be able to build both and run both, is that possible? Thank you!

Comment: If you have multiple java classes, you should build a proper java project and use some build tool like Maven or gradle to build your project. your output would most likely be a jar file, which you can execute with java -jar command.

Comment: ah, so its not possible to do it using the inbuilt windows script tool? Alright, I'm going to look into Maven and see how to use that. One other question, how would I set the directory such that it is able to "read" all the files in the java project? Or are you saying that with maven, I can just set the root folder as the directory and it will take care of all the .java files within it? thank you for responding.